# How do I implement and return a Cmd Msg?

Tags: elm

How do I implement and return a Cmd Msg?

For example, the following line generates a *Cmd Msg*:

```
Http.send msg request
```

It's used in the following function:

```
tryRegister : Form -> (Result Http.Error JsonProfile -> msg) -> Cmd msg
tryRegister form msg =
    let
        registerUrl =
            "http://localhost:5000/register"

        body =
            encode form |> Http.jsonBody

        request =
            Http.post registerUrl body decoder
    in
        Http.send msg request
```

I'm trying to hand code a similar function within my TestAPI:

```
tryRegister : Form -> (Result Http.Error JsonProfile -> msg) -> Cmd msg
tryRegister form msg =
    Cmd.none
```

The above code compiles. However, it's not clear to me how to implement a function that returns a Cmd Msg other than Cmd.none.

**Appendix:**

```
type Msg
    =
    ...
    | Submit
    | Response (Result Http.Error JsonProfile)

update : Msg -> Form -> ( Form, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
       ...
       Submit ->
           ( model, runtime.tryRegister model Response )
```

[Source code on GitHub](https://github.com/Lambda-Cartel/Nikeza/blob/master/Client/app/Tests/TestAPI.elm).

Comment: Didn't peruse your code, but you might be able to achieve what you're trying to do without commands: https://medium.com/elm-shorts/how-to-turn-a-msg-into-a-cmd-msg-in-elm-5dd095175d84

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**

The original answer suggested mapping over `Cmd.none`, which compiles and may potentially be useful when mocking out functions for testing, but if you are actually trying to force another `update` cycle in The Elm Architecture, you will need to convert to a `Task`, as outlined in the `send` function [described here](https://medium.com/elm-shorts/how-to-turn-a-msg-into-a-cmd-msg-in-elm-5dd095175d84).

```
send : msg -> Cmd msg
send msg =
    Task.succeed msg
        |> Task.perform identity
```

As @SwiftsNamesake mentioned above, in most cases this is not necessary, and the entire blog post on the subject is [worth a read](https://medium.com/elm-shorts/how-to-turn-a-msg-into-a-cmd-msg-in-elm-5dd095175d84).

**Original Answer**

You can use [`Cmd.map`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Platform-Cmd#map) over `Cmd.none` to change it to any `Cmd`:

```elm
Cmd.map (always Submit) Cmd.none
```